# Module Function frm.setfocus runtime 2449 error

Tags: function, vba, ms-access, setfocus

I have a problem with a function where it is causing a "RunTime error 2449, There is an invalid method in an expression" on the frm.setfocus line. The form being referred to is a subform, please can anyone help with this error?

The function is:

```
Function NewItemsSaveAfter(frm As Form)

If frm.Parent.PartSaveYesNo = "Yes" Then
    varCurrRec = frm.CurrentRecord
    frm.Parent.Form.Refresh
    frm.SetFocus
    DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acGoTo, varCurrRec
Else
End If

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the focus to the child control containing the subform.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, pardon my ignorance but how do i do that?

Comment: Click the border of the subform (when showing in main form), you will get the name of the control (let's say `subX`) containing the subform (in Properties). then use `ParentForm.subX.SetFocus`

Comment: cheers, that won't work for me as the module function can be called from different subforms so I really need to use the "frm" variable.