# Setting focus to a subform gives the error 2449 (there is an invalid method in an expression) - VBA - Access 2013

Tags: forms, vba, ms-access, setfocus

**-----------UPDATE---------**

I figured out how to get the focus on my subform. If it is a subform then :

```
ParentFormName = frm.Parent.Name
SubFormName = frm.Name

Forms(ParentFormName).Form(SubFormName).SetFocus
```

This seems to work (although Andre451's post is more effective). But this resulted in the underlying problem of my subform causing the suspended state. My subform is relatively big (194 records) and when doing a MoveFirst/Last on the recordset of larger records I get the error `3021 (no current record)`. This probably has something to do with the entire recordset of the subform isn't loaded on the load event of the main form. Smaller recordsets can be looped faster so won't generate the error (this is just an assumption though).

The *new* question is: How can I avoid the `3021 error` and let the subform records load entirely so I can move through them with either:

1. DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdRecordsGoToLast

OR

2. frm.RecordsetClone.MoveLast

**----------------------------------------------------------------------------------**

A while a go we migrated our Access data to a SQL server with still using the Access as the frontend. We did this by linking the SQL Server tables with Access and this all works (almost) fine. Recently however we encountered a problem with Access queries getting in `suspended state` on the SQL server (mainly happens on queries in combo boxes).

After some research we figured out that this could be solved by looping through the query records on the load of the form (so by doing a simple `acCmdRecordsGoToLast` and `acCmdRecordsGoToFirst`) and this seems to work. 
So to counter this suspended state we added to each forms load an `init` that runs through the records of the `recordsource` and `rowsource` (the main forms recordsource, the comboxes rowsource etc.).

So on a forms load:

```
modFunctions.InitForm(Me)
```

This init is in a module and looks like this:

```
    Dim InitFormResult As Boolean

    InitFormResult = InitFormRecordSource(frm)  ' Initialize the recordsource of the form
    InitFormComboBoxes frm          ' Initialize all the comboboxes on the form
    InitFormCommandButton frm       ' Initialize all the buttons on the form
```

The first init of the forms RecordSource (where the error happens) looks like this:

```
Public Function InitFormRecordSource(frm As Form) As Boolean

    If frm.RecordSource <> "" Then  ' if recordsource found
        On Error GoTo ErrHandler

        frm.SetFocus

        DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdRecordsGoToLast
        DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdRecordsGoToFirst

        GoTo EndSuccess

ErrHandler:
       MsgBox (Err.Number)
        Debug.Print "ERROR during InitFormRecordSource in form : " & frm.Name
        InitFormRecordSource = False
        Exit Function
EndSuccess:
    InitFormRecordSource = True

    Else
        InitFormRecordSource = True
    End If
End Function
```

To run through the forms recordset with First and Last it needs to have the focus. This all works great for one form but it doesn't for Subforms in a main form. In subforms we want to counter the suspended state as well by also running through the subforms records, though when using the above code we keep getting the `error 2449`.

After some research I encountered this post: [Module Function frm.setfocus runtime 2449 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23384037/module-function-frm-setfocus-runtime-2449-error) which is more or less the same problem. So I figured out that a subform needs to be given it's focus in a different way, yet all my efforts to do this won't work.

What I tried so far:

```
If frm.RecordSource <> "" Then  ' if recordsource found
        On Error GoTo ErrHandler

        Dim HasParent As Boolean
        Dim sParentForm
        HasParent = TypeName(frm.Parent.Name) = "String"

        If HasParent = True Then 'The form is a subform
            'sParentForm = frm.Parent
            'sParentForm.frm.SetFocus
            'frm.Parent.frm.SetFocus
            'sParentForm!frm.SetFocus
        Else
            frm.SetFocus
        End If


        DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdRecordsGoToLast
        DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdRecordsGoToFirst

        GoTo EndSuccess
```

The tried fixes are all commented out in the above code. The `HasParent` does work, with this I can check if the form is a subform (it has a parent) or not and setting the focus differently.

Though I can't seem to get the focus on the subform and I don't quite know how to get it fixed!

Answer (score 1):

I have had a similar problem, queries on Sql Server 2008 R2 going into a "ASYNC_NETWORK_IO" wait state, until the last record was loaded.

My solution: don't use the form itself to go to the last record, but its `.RecordsetClone`:

```
frm.RecordsetClone.MoveLast
```

Comment: Thank you Andre451 your solution is a bit easier than what I was using so i Copied it! Though while waiting for a response on this message I already figured out how to get the focus on my subform, though I found out that the real problem was not this. The real problem is that 2 of my subforms have a relative large recordset - 194 records and I cant do the `frm.RecordsetClone.MoveLast` neither can I do the what I used before on these (gives the error 3021 - no current record). This is prob. got to do with the subform data is not loaded on the load event of the main form.. So what to do now?;)

Comment: Also updated the above text, and your suggestion to an update in the main post!